# tag-it input store only last value in DB laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4, tag-it

i am using Jquery Tag-it. When i pass tag-it values to controller and check it by var_dump(); all the values post perfectly but the problem i that when it pass to DB it will **store only last value** .. please help me out

```html
<input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="wish-tags" class="form-control">
```

**Controller**

```
$wishlist = Wishlist::firstOrNew(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
        if (!empty($wishlist)) {
            $locations = $request->input('wish-tags');
            //var_dump($locations); exit();
            foreach (explode(",", $locations) as $location) {

                $wishlist->update([
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'locations' => $location,

                ]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It happens because of foreach loop. But it's unclear how to solve this without seeing data structure and relationships you use. Also, for saving tags usually you want to use many-to-many relationship.

Comment: ok.. but please explain how to create many-to-many relation between User and Wishlist tags?

Comment: You should create a pivot table and two `belongsToMany()` relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many - After that use `sync()` method to sync tags. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$locations = $request->input('wish-tags');
//var_dump($locations); exit();
foreach (explode(",", $locations) as $location) {
$wishlist = Wishlist::firstOrNew(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'locations' => $location ]);
        if (!empty($wishlist)) {
          $wishlist->update([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'locations' => $location,
          ]);
       }
 }
```